# Existence of solution for a particular linear, non-strictly hyperbolic system of PDEs.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, hyperbolic-equations

I've made a quick search but I haven't been able to find anything regarding a particular type of this (first order)  linear, non-strictly hyperbolic system of PDEs.

$$u_t+A(t)u_x=h(t,u,x)$$

where $A(t)$  is an scaled version of the $(2\times 2)$-identity matrix, this is both eigenvalues are $f(t)$.

In general literature conditions are given for the existence of the solution of a strictly hyperbolic system, but clearly those do not apply here.

Do you know  if it is possible to  show the existence of a solution for this system? (under certain conditions for $f$ and $h$ of course).

This may be some well-known result, but this is not my field of study and I am rather ignorant, so please let me know if the question is trivial or non well-posed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think so....? because the strict hyperbolicity is used to diagonalise the coefficient of $u_x$, but yours is already diagonal...?  (only learned a little of the relevant theory)

Comment: Thanks for for comment @CalvinKhor, I wasn't aware of this detail, this problem arised in my research in probability and honestly I don't know almost anything regarding it. In all the books I've consulted the condition of strict hypebolicity was  assumed without explaining why

Comment: I have only briefly looked at an introductory book of Serge Alinhac ("Hyperbolic Partial Differential Equations"), and not too recently, but you might want to have a look at the proofs of theorem 2.21 and 2.22 to verify where strict hyperbolicity is used. As "published lecture notes", its not as cleanly stated as I would like it to be and you may need to backtrack for notation etc

Comment: @CalvinKhor  Still if the aim is to diagonalize the matrix of coefficients, why assume that all the eigenvalues are distinct? Isn't it a much stronger assumption?

Comment: Perhaps there is something I'm missing, or perhaps it affects some qualitative behavior that is more specific than mere existence and uniqueness. I'm afraid I'm not sure!

Comment: @CalvinKhor Nevermind! Thanks for the reference though, I may try asking someone in my university or make a try at MO!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's think in terms of characteristics, and assume a parametrization $(x(t), t)$ of the coordinates such that $x'(t) = f(t)$. Using the chain rule for the time-derivative of $u(x(t), t)$, we find
$$
\frac{\text d}{\text d t} u = u_t + f(t) u_x = h \, .
$$
Local existence and uniqueness results follow from the study of the ODE system $$
\begin{aligned}
x'(t) &= f(t)\\
u'(t) &= h\big(t, u(t), x(t)\big)
\end{aligned}
$$
Here, we have used the fact that $A = f\, I_2$ is proportional to the identity matrix, as noted by @Calvin Khor in the comments section. It is one particular example where the method of characteristics applies to PDE systems.

Comment: I recently came back to this question and I realized that I hadn't accept it. Sorry for that. One question still remains, I always thought that the method of characteristics could be applied only to scalar PDEs, am I wrong?

Comment: But if the non-homegeneity $h$ depends on both solutions then how to decouple them? Here h depends on the vector solution $u$

Comment: Oh nice, do you know of some reference for this ? Namely for the application of characteristics to systems. By the way, will this be still true in the case of $N$ equations with $K$ state variables?

Comment: @Chaos Yes. As long as all $N$ variables share the same characteristic curves, the PDE system can be transformed into an ODE system using the method of characteristics. I could recommend the books by LeVeque (2002) or Godlewski & Raviard (1996).